# Status of Spark View Engine

Tags: .net, asp.net, spark-view-engine

It’s been a while since the community got any feature releases from the spark team. Has it ceased development? With the advent of Razor, has Louis moved on?
The least [release was in March](http://sparkviewengine.codeplex.com/releases/view/27601) and the [last development build](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=14262&buildTypeId=bt47&tab=buildChangesDiv) was in July

Answer (score 9):

Spark most certainly isn't dead. I'm happy to say that version 1.5 has just be released with full compatability with .NET 3.5 and 4 projects and ASP.NET MVC 2 and 3.

You can read the [release notes here](http://sparkviewengine.codeplex.com/releases/view/60090), and you can either download from there or you can get it as a [NuGet package reference](http://nuget.org/Packages/Search?packageType=Packages&searchCategory=All+Categories&searchTerm=Spark) direct in VS2010

I have written about [Razor and Spark here](http://blog.robertgreyling.com/2010/07/is-razor-just-wolf-in-sparks-clothing.html), and as a final note, development on Spark hasn't stopped - there just haven't been that many feature requests over the last few months - mainly just bug fixes and this is a clear sign that it is a mature framework, not a dying one.

Hope that helps,
Rob

Comment: I know this sounds panicky but the spark view engine website is down since last week... I wonder what's going on

Comment: hosting issues - we're currently moving servers - don't panic :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, the pace is not furious but there has certainly been activity since March:

http://github.com/loudej/spark/commits/master

I hope that Razor does not kill Spark.  They are very complementary.

Spark is really mark-up with some code in it while Razor is more like code containing mark-up.